Stripe - two webhooks
I offer two different things on my website. One is buying website tokens and one is buying VIP membership. Therefore I need to handle this through two webhooks, I believe.

When user buys a VIP membership -> use webhook 1
When user buys other service -> use webhook 2

How can I do this on same website? Should I create two accounts in Stripe dashboard and use different keys when calling Stripe APIs?

That sounds unlikely to me. Most of the time the events, coming in on a single webhook, will tell you what they are about. One webhook should be sufficient. See: Receive Stripe events in your webhook endpoint.

How can I know what was it about? I don't see a way to link anything to webhook/session. Ok I can add custom field but that one will only be available in "checkout.session.completed" while for other events I will have no idea what item (1 or 2) they belong too. Any idea?

If you sell both products on the same website, it is recommended to use a single Stripe webhook.
You can differentiate between the two products by implementing one of these options:

Store the unique payment id after initiating the checkout process together with what the user buys in your backend. Retrieve this again when you receive the payment confirmation with the webhook.
Add metadata to the stripe payment which specifies what the user buys when you initiate the checkout. The metadata is sent back with the payment confirmation webhook.
Register your products with Stripes product API and link them to the payment when initiating the checkout process. To retrieve them again when you receive the payment confirmation with the webhook, the line items API can be used.


Just in case you used ChatGTP to generate this answer, see: What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools? If you copied this from somewhere else, then always link to the source. If it is an answer here on Stack Overflow, then mark the question as a duplicate. If you actually are knowledgeable about this topic: What kept you away from Stack Overflow for so long? Welcome!

Nope, I have written this on my own. Based on my experience with Stripe. I had to make a similar decision earlier this year with invoice numbers which I had to store per payment.

@KIKOSoftware I finally want to get to 15 points so that I can up and downvote answers, that's why I decided to write some answers.

This is so complicated. I will try with what @robin mentioned but from what I see upon charge, Stripe calls my webhook routine many times and the only "useful" events for me seem to be checkout.session.completed (i can read client_reference_id here - metadata) and charge.succeeded (url to invoice). preferrably i would want just one event but probably it doesnt work that way. Robin, i can only read metadata from checkout.session.completed but then i wont know about other events to what charge they belong to, unless i do parsing of everything and somehow connect all the events outputs?

The problem is also that Stripe calls these events randomly or all at the same time...

You can select which events get sent and which not when you configure the webhook in the dashboard.
Instead of parsing the response from the webhook manually I can recommend you using an SDK from Stripe, in your case the one for PHP I guess:
https://docs.stripe.com/sdks

Robin, this looks good -- $stripe->products->create(['name' => 'Gold Plan']); --- but will EVERY response (all events) have this product somewhere in output? It would be perfect!

Is there a way to chat 1:1 here somehow?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
